# Moving from TestTrack to JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, testtrack

what are the steps involved in moving from TestTrack to JIRA?

Comment: There is a Ruby script available which shows the steps involved to migrate from Testtrack to Jira:

https://github.com/vijedi/testtrack_to_jira

Answer (score 2):

I've done a few migrations from TestTrack to JIRA over the last 5 years. It's always more work than I expect (weeks not days). The migrations I did used a custom migration application that read the data from the TestTrack database (not the simplest of schemas) and then imported it into JIRA using a custom SOAP API. Nowadays I think I might go with a more focused approach and use a single customized script to create CSV suitable for the JIRA CSV importer. This will get you the issue fields, comments and attachments. Links are separate thing, but no issue history.

The JIRA CSV importer works, though the flattening of the data restricts what it can do significantly. The hardest thing is usually mapping of values from one system to another - are the userids *really* identical in both systems?

If you want to investigate doing the migration commercially, please contact info@customware.net (my employer)